# Android studio build apk or generate signer apk error

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, github, cloud

I was clone a project from github. While I'm trying to build apk getting the following error

[image: this is the screenshot of the error]

project contains lots of cpp files. github project link: https://github.com/litecoin-foundation/loafwallet-android